# JavaScript Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is a sample screenshot of my project...

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D60mEG9.jpg]

the yellow balls keep blinking until you click on it, when it is clicked the yellow ball becomes blue and a box too pops up with a video and few images... I need to add a javaScript animation when the ball is clicked the box should slide in with a beatiful animation.  I tried it many times no luck.

Help me out guys please.

This is the CSS for the box

```
#mainbox {
    background-color:#084679;
    height: 290px;
    width: 497px;
    position:absolute;
}
#videobox {
    background-color:#084679;
    height: 169px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 19px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox1 {
    background-color: #0dd4d7;
    height: 62px;
    width: 110px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 211px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox2 {
    background-color: #0dd4d7;
    height: 62px;
    width: 110px;
    left: 136px;
    top: 211px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox3 {
    background-color:#0dd4d7;
    height: 62px;
    width: 110px;
    left: 257px;
    top: 211px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox4 {
    background-color:#0dd4d7;
    height: 62px;
    width: 110px;
    left: 378px;
    top: 211px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox5 {
    background-color: #084679;
    height: 62px;
    width: 110px;
    left: 330px;
    top: 60px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is the JavaScript

```
$('#c1').click(function () {
                setPos();

                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');
                clearCircle()


                $(this).removeClass("blink1");
                //$(this).addClass("blink1");
                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');

                $(this).css('top', 90 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 120 - ((190 - 60) / 2));

                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/blue_back.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').css('top', '160px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('left', '165px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox1').show();

            })

            $('#c2').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                $(this).removeClass("blink2");
                // $(this).addClass("blink2");
                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 360 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 665 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/1.png)');
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox').css('top', '440px');
                $('#mainbox').css('left', '200px');
                $('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox').show();

            })


            $('#c3').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 721 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 206 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink3");
                // $(this).addClass("blink3");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/2.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').css('top', '785px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('left', '265px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox1').show();

            })


            $('#c4').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()

                $(this).css('z-index', '1');
                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 500 - (
                (190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 661 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink4");
                //$(this).addClass("blink4");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/3.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').css('top', '550px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('left', '738px');
                $('#mainbox1').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox1').show();

            })


            $('#c5').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 154 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1291 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink5");
                //$(this).addClass("blink5");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/5.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox').css('top', '223px');
                $('#mainbox').css('left', '820px');
                $('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox').show();

            })


            $('#c6').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 309 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1488 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink6");
                // $(this).addClass("blink6");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/6.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox').css('top', '390px');
                $('#mainbox').css('left', '1025px');
                $('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox').show();

            })


            $('#c7').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                //$(this).css('background-color','#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 608 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1488 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink7");
                // $(this).addClass("blink7");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/7.png)');

                $('#mainbox').hide();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox').css('top', '680px');
                $('#mainbox').css('left', '1025px');
                $('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox').show();

            })

            $('#c8').click(function () {
                setPos()
                $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
                $('.circle').css('height', '60px');

                clearCircle()


                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 711 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1635 - ((190 - 60) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink8");
                // $(this).addClass("blink8");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/8.png)');

                $('#mainbox').show();
                $('#mainbox1').hide();
                $('#mainbox').css('top', '785px');
                $('#mainbox').css('left', '1170px');
                $('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
                $('#mainbox').show();

            })

        })

        function clearCircle() {

            $('.circle').css('background-image', '');
        }

        function ResetCircle() {
            $('.circle').css('width', '60px');
            $('.circle').css('height', '60px');
        }

        //<!--  Postion tags-->

        function clearCircle() {

            $('.circle').css('background-image', '');
        }

        function setPos() {

            if ($('#c1').width() == 190) {
                $('#c1').css('top', 90);
                $('#c1').css('left', 120);
                $('#c1').addClass("blink1");
            }
            if ($('#c2').width() == 190) {
                $('#c2').css('top', 360);
                $('#c2').css('left', 665);
                $('#c2').addClass("blink2");
            }

            if ($('#c3').width() == 190) {
                $('#c3').css('top', 721);
                $('#c3').css('left', 206);
                $('#c3').addClass("blink3");
            }

            if ($('#c4').width() == 190) {
                $('#c4').css('top', 500);
                $('#c4').css('left', 661);
                $('#c4').addClass("blink4");
            }

            if ($('#c5').width() == 190) {
                $('#c5').css('top', 154);
                $('#c5').css('left', 1291);
                $('#c5').addClass("blink5");
            }

            if ($('#c6').width() == 190) {
                $('#c6').css('top', 309);
                $('#c6').css('left', 1488);
                $('#c6').addClass("blink6");

            }

            if ($('#c7').width() == 190) {
                $('#c7').css('top', 608);
                $('#c7').css('left', 1420);
                $('#c7').addClass("blink7");
            }

            if ($('#c8').width() == 190) {
                $('#c8').css('top', 711);
                $('#c8').css('left', 1635);
                $('#c8').addClass("blink8");
            }
        }
```

Comment: *".i tried it many times no luck"* ***How***, exactly? And what did it do instead of what you expected it to do?

Comment: When i click on the circle the box should animate and come in!!

Comment: Pls dont downrate guys! I wnt be able to get any help in future :(

Comment: *"When i click on the circle the box should animate and come in!!"* Yes. That doesn't, in any way, answer the question I asked. Also: Asking people not to downvote your question is ***at best*** useless, and much more likely to be counter-productive. If you want your questions to be upvoted (or at least not downvoted), take time and care to ask a good question, which would at a minimum explain what you tried "many times".

Comment: @DrekJohn try to localize and isolate your problem, this will make people more likely to help you :)

Comment: are you asking for once you click on the yellow circle, an animation of 'fade' appears and opens the blue box?

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer I wrote?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ill try my best to ask better questions next time Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: @Hybrid82 Yes Exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best and easiest jquery animation or effect is jquery ui 
here you will find examples and .js files

http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 0):

If you want animation instead of just positioning, then use **`.animate()` instead of `.css()`**, like this:

```
function AnimatePosition(TheSelector, SomeTopValue, SomeLeftValue. SomeWidthValue, SomeHeightValue) {

    TheSelector.animate({ top: SomeTopValue,
                          left: SomeLeftValue
                          width: SomeWidthValue,
                          height: SomeHeightValue}, 500);
}
```

and then to use it, since you seem to be doing this type of changes a lot, you call it lke this, using selector caching:

```
TheSelector = $(this); //or TheSelector = $('#mainbox1'); or another element
TheTop = 721 - ((190 - 60) / 2);
TheLeft = 206 - ((190 - 60) / 2);
TheHeight = 190;
TheWidth = 190;

AnimatePosition(TheSelector, TheTop, TheLeft, TheWidth, TheHeight);
```

Just a suggestion that can help: **chain and cache your selectors!**

When you write something like this:

```
$('#mainbox').hide();
$('#mainbox').css('top', '440px');
$('#mainbox').css('left', '200px');
$('#mainbox').css('z-index', '');
$('#mainbox').show();
```

you can write this:

`var mainbox = $('#mainbox');` or `var This = $(this);` so that you don't have to reevaluate `$('#mainbox')` or `$(this)` every line. In fact, in your case, you should use chaining and write this (note that `.css()` can also take an object):

```
$('#mainbox').hide()
             .css({'top': '440px', 'left': '200px', 'z-index': '' })
             .show();
```

Comment: You accidently left the semicolons at the end of each line inside your chain.

Comment: @Sparky: yes, I did; just fixed it, thanks.